# Join over substring across tables in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with one table with one column having a URL and another table having a substring from that URL

Table 1

```
Id  | URL
----------
1    ...\aaa_common\
2    ...\aaa_qa..
3    ...\aaa_test\Analytics
```

Table 2

```
SomeId | compname
-----------------
1         aaa_common
2         aaa_qa
3         aaa_test
```

It is possible to join using string functions (charindex and substring) . But is there an easier alternative?

Comment: Please see below ans & example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join using like, but it will be a bit of a performance hit.

```
select
  *
from
  table_1 t1

  inner join table_2 t2 on
     t1.url like concat('%',t2.compname, '%')
```

Comment: t2.compname should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use join, but not sure that this is best method, cause join on string is not good idea, also I am not sure about repetitive values in your table. Still if require to do so, I will suggest you to have one more column in your Table1, in which you can update only compname from same table using sub-string & then join both tables including new column from Table1 & compname from Table2.

Also for using sub-string you should be 100% sure with index/pattern of your compname in string of Table1.

Please look into this **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd887/24)**

Just has example of join on string using sub-string & charindex